# Anorm insert with trigger

Tags: mysql, scala, scala-2.10, anorm

I have a table with a trigger that updates a column in the table after the insert. Problem is this is returning false:

```
  def insert(user: User, token: String) = {
    DB.withConnection {
      implicit connection =>
        SQL(INSERT_STMT).on("user_id" -> user.id, "token" -> token).execute()
    }
  }
```

The values get inserted correctly after the call but the function returns false. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.executeUpdate()` for DML's DDL's which return rowcounts/nothing

Learn more from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

I wish I knew more about SQL and Scala - so for the time I'll leverage my Google skills and take a shot at this - I believe this guy solved your question:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/r2Iueso3yGQ

From the API, it would appear you get back false - if the result type is a rowcount:

Returns:
    true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the first result is an update count or there is no result